# Weird connection on JavaFX launch

Tags: java, connection, javafx

It seems lately, my JavaFX app always tries to connect to something upon launch.
This process hangs my app for a bit and makes my app startup time about 20 seconds more longer. This is the error I see:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unkno
wn Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.getJSFileFromURL(Un
known Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.init(Unknown Source
)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DynamicProxyManager.reset(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DeployProxySelector.reset(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.tryToSetProxy(Main.java:572)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:640)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown So
urce)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown So
urce)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.isSupportedINSFile(
Unknown Source)
        ... 10 more
```

I don't see it trying to connect if I'm running from the IDE. So is this some sort of oracle-based spying attempt? What gives?

Comment: How do you package and run your application (what are the specific commands you use)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's trying to auto-detect a proxy somehow.

I was able to make this go away in the Java Control Panel.  On the `General` tab, in the `Network Settings...` dialog, switch from `Use browser settings` to `Direct connection`.

(I couldn't find any proxy settings specified in either Firefox or IE, though.)